# How to add Two more Button sharepoint List column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Creating Shrepoint deign page. in creating list . in the list last column have i need to add three button.previous i added one button like this method use calculated column datatype choose number added following formula

```
="<button onclick=""alert('Hello World!')"">Interim Testing</button>"
```

Now I want add two button how can i add? follow this way i cant able to add button? using sharepoint Designer 2010. please any one give some idea about it

Comment: Do you mean 3 buttons in the same column or 3 different columns?

Comment: same column sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

```
="<button onclick=""alert('You clicked One')"">1</button>"
 &"<button onclick=""alert('You clicked Two')"">2</button>"
 &"<button onclick=""alert('You clicked Three')"">3</button>"
```

But, you will run in all sorts of programming trouble if you could not answer this yourself and you clearly do not have the required HTML & programming skills

Forcing code into a Calculated Column is not for the faint-hearted.
If you want to learn whats possible use the search box in the top right and search for 'icc'
*and you should learn from those posts before asking more questions*